# CMake recursively add all source files inside all subdirectories of a directory to the executable?

Tags: linux, cmake

I have a pretty big file structure of a project which I need to convert into a multiplatform cmake project. Now it seams that cmake requires ever single  cpp file be added individually to the executable. But is there a script that automates this? That snoopes through the file structure and just adds every source file automatically? Since the project will probably get a lot more source files and I probably wont be able to manually add every single one.

Comment: `file(GLOB ...)` is your friend.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: Unfortunatley they explicitly state in the wiki that it should not be used to search for source files, since cmake doesn't rebuild the makefiles if no cmake files have changed. But I'll probably do it anyway and create a shellscript wich forces cmake to rebuild every time I add a file to the project. Thanks for your help

Comment: "I probably wont be able to manually add every single one" -- Why not?

Comment: It was supposed to be a case were I would just be able to create the CMake script once and then never think about it again for the most party. it was supposed to be possible to just create new files on the fly and only edit the files when new librarys were necessary.  But it seams thats just not possible

Answer (score 3):

You could use `execute_process()` with a `cmake -P` script that uses globbing to recursively scan for source files which writes to an included file in your `CMakeLists.txt` i.e. something like:

"CMakeLists.txt":

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
  -D "RDIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
  -P "scansources.cmake"
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
include("sources.cmake")
add_executable(myexe ${sources})
```

"scansources.cmake" (generates "sources.cmake"):

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE sourcelist
  *.c
  *.cc
  *.cpp
  *.cxx)
string(REGEX REPLACE "${RDIR}/" "" relative_sources "${sourcelist}")
string(REPLACE ";" "\n" sources_string "${relative_sources}")
set(sources_string "set(sources\n${sources_string})")
file(WRITE sources.cmake "${sources_string}")
```

The reason why this works is because `execute_process()` occurs at configure time.

You could, of course, generate `sources.cmake` via some other tool or IDE then you wouldn't need `scansources.cmake` or `execute_process()`.

Comment: so basicly set up a script that executes cmake everytime I want to compile my programm, followed by make -j4, and then have rescan the files. I know that cmake doesn't search them automaticly if you just cmake again on its own, globbing for the source files, but this might actually solve this, thanks